# Is there a reverse proxy that can make SPDY connections to a back-end?

Tags: reverse-proxy, spdy, backend

...other than spdylay in --spdy-relay mode?

We've got a situation where a reverse-proxy has to talk SSL to a Tomcat server, and I'd love to test the performance boost of SPDY. Apache and Nginx both speak SPDY on the front, but as near as I can tell not on the ProxyPass side.

I saw a request that suggested that Nginx wouldn't get it for a while, but the post was from 2012 and referenced v1.3

As there been any movement in this area that I'm just not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) was the first Java server to support SPDY, and it does have a [SPDY reverse proxy](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy-configuring-proxy.html) that supports SPDY towards the backend (along with HTTP).

Since Jetty is one of the few servers (if not the only) that is able to perform [SPDY Push](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy-configuring-push.html) in a transparent way for applications (check [this video](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/) that shows the big performance benefits of SPDY Push in Jetty) , being able to talk SPDY from the reverse proxy to the backend can give a real boost thanks to SPDY Push being performed from the backend to the proxy to the client.